# What's the best way to represent the several states of things in java?

Tags: java

Say I have a `char array`, I wanna classify its element into three states. If it's a number, then mark it as `State 1`, if it's a operator, then mark it as `State 2`, if else, mark it `State 3`.

First, I initialize a `boolean array` to represent its state, but I fount it only can store two states:(

Then I switch to `int array`, yet this way is kinda a waste of space.

Could you offer better idea please?

Comment: You're looking for [`enum`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need to represent something like the state of a finite state machine, or Values of an hypothetical class Card, you should use enum, something like

```
public class EnumTest {

    public enum State{
        START_STATE("1"),INTER_STATE("2"),END_STATE("3");

        String name;
        State(String name){this.name = name;}
        String getName() {return name;}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(State state : EnumTest.State.values())
            System.out.println(state.getName());
    }
}
```

PS: Constructor and fields are actually optional if space matters: your enum can also be

```
public enum{FIRST,SECOND,THIRD;}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this SO page: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952169/what-is-the-third-boolean-state-in-java](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952169/what-is-the-third-boolean-state-in-java), you could also use a wrapped Boolean defaulting to null, which could potentially be used as a third type if you do not reassign the boolean to any other value.

Comment: Just an opinion of course, but you shouldn't have `null` mean something, IMHO.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I agree with you entirely upon this point, but it can still be used in case one really wants to use a Boolean labelled as such.